# Multi level drop down listing in Vue js

Tags: vue.js

I have been searching for 3 level category listing sample. I found few samples for 2 levels. The below sample derived from 2 levels.

I was facing an issue with triggering v-model computed event after selecting subcategory item, to solve this we need to add v-model="subcategory" and the same has to be declared in data()

Click [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EoByoQ)

```
 **HTML**

<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' 
href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.4.2/css/bulma.min.css'>
<div class="container" id="app">
   <div class="section">
       <h1 class="title">Vue.js - Conditional Select</h1>
   <hr>
      <conditional-select 

        :categories="categories":newcategories="newcategories" 
                  :subcategories="subcategories" ></conditional-select>

   </div><!-- /.section -->
   </div><!-- /.container -->

 **Vue.js**

 Vue.component('conditional-select', {
     template: `
                 <div id="ConditionalSelect">
                     <div class="select">
                       <select v-model="category" name="category">
                        <option v-for="category in categories" 
          :value="category.id">{{ category.name }}</option>
        </select>
     </div>

    <div class="select">
        <select v-model="subcategory" name="subcategory">
            <option v-for="subcategory in conditionalSubcategories" 
    :value="subcategory.subid" :selected="subcategory.selected == true">{{ 
    subcategory.name }}</option>
        </select>  
    </div>

   <div class="select">
        <select name="newcategory">
            <option v-for="newcategory in conditionalNewcategories" 
   :value="newcategory.id" :selected="newcategory.selected == true">{{ 
   newcategory.name }}</option>
        </select>  
      </div>

    </div>
`,

    props: ['categories', 'subcategories', 'newcategories'],

      data() {
           return {
             category: '',
               subcategory: '',
         }
        },

  computed: {
        conditionalSubcategories() {

            return this.subcategories.filter(subcategory => {
                return subcategory.category_id == this.category;
            });
        },
   conditionalNewcategories() {

            return this.newcategories.filter(newcategory => {
                return newcategory.subcategory_id == this.subcategory;
            });
        },

    },

created() {
    let category = this.categories.find(category => {
        return category.selected == true;
    });

let subcategory = this.subcategories.find(subcategory => {
        return subcategory.selected == true;
    });   


    this.category = category.id;
this.subcategory = subcategory.subid;


}
});

     var app = new Vue({
         el: '#app',

          data: {
                categories: [
        { id: '0', name: 'Select a category', selected: true },
        { id: '1', name: 'Games', selected: false },
        { id: '2', name: 'Apps', selected: false }
       ],
      subcategories: [
        { subid: '0', category_id:'1',  name: 'Select a subcategory', 
      selected: 
        false },
        { subid: '1', category_id:'1',  name: 'Adventure', selected: false 
     },
        { subid: '2', category_id:'1',  name: 'Shooter', selected: false },
        { subid: '3', category_id:'1',  name: 'Simulation', selected: false 
     },
        { subid: '4', category_id:'1',  name: 'Sports', selected: false },
        { subid: '5', category_id:'2',  name: 'Illustration', selected: 
     false },
        { subid: '6', category_id:'2',  name: 'Music Production', selected: 
     false },
        { subid: '7', category_id:'2',  name: 'Webdesign', selected: false 
     },
        { subid: '8', category_id:'2',  name: 'Office', selected: false },
     ],

      newcategories: [

        { id: '1', subcategory_id:'1',  name: 'New Adventure', selected: 
    false },
        { id: '2', subcategory_id:'1',  name: 'New Shooter', selected: false 
   },
        { id: '3', subcategory_id:'1',  name: 'New Simulation', selected: 
  false },
        { id: '4', subcategory_id:'1',  name: 'New Sports', selected: false 
    },
  { id: '5', subcategory_id:'2',  name: 'New Illustration', selected: false 
   },
        { id: '6', subcategory_id:'2',  name: 'New Music Production', 
  selected: false },
        { id: '7', subcategory_id:'2',  name: 'New Webdesign', selected: 
  false },
        { id: '8', subcategory_id:'2',  name: 'NewOffice', selected: false 
   },

      ],

     }
  });
```

Comment: Can you please share what you tried?

Comment: I found this as 2 level drop down, I just enhanced it to 3 level drop down. The early codepen link had only 2 level. I was searching this example for 2 days but not found. I figured it out by adding v-model in the subcategory. Hence posting so that others can be implemented in their project